# Automatic form submit

Tags: javascript, php, dom-events

I have this form into PHP pages:

```
echo "<form action=\"xxx.php\" method=\"post\" id=\"test\" name=\"test\">
 <input type=\"submit\" name=\"oooo\" value=\"Sincronizza\"> 
</form>";
```

On top I have this JavaScript for automatic submit:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
<!-- 
function send() {
var objForm = document.getElementById('test');
objForm.action='xxx.php';
objForm.submit();
}

window.setTimeout('send()', 5000)

//--> 
</script>
```

Unfortunately, the script start an refresh page and not an auto-submitting.

What is the problem?

Comment: Why set a timeout instead of submitting straight away if that's what you want to do? And can you clarify what exactly happens when?

Comment: I need a submitting every 5 minutes for example. Refresh page

Comment: What exactly happens and what would you like to happen? You mean it's refreshing the page instead of going to xxx.php?

Comment: What is the relation between the `'xxx.php'` script and the script that generates the original web-page? Is it the same script?

Comment: xxx.php is the current page is not another page. I want that script process form but when i start page i receive only a refresh.

Comment: @user1499315 You're doing a postback then. The page is supposed to refresh. That's how postbacks work. The page is submitted and the response is that same page, so you perceive it as a refresh.

Comment: Sorry, submit not start beacuase php function not start

Comment: @user1499315 The PHP function doesn't execute?

Comment: I have an php page, on this page there is a form, on submit form start post php function. I want to start post php function automatically every 5 minutes for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JavaScript to submit, the value of the submit-input tag is not posted. A solution could be to include a hidden type input in the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="oooo" value="Sincronizza">
```